# Apache Beam: How To Simultaneously Create Many PCollections That Undergo Same PTransform?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Thanks in advance!

**[+] Issue:**

I have a lot of files on google cloud, for every file I have to:

1. get the file
2. Make a bunch of Google-Cloud-Storage API calls on each file to index it(e.g. name = blob.name, size = blob.size)
3. unzip it
4. search for stuff in there
5. put the indexing information + stuff found inside file in a BigQuery Table

I've been using **python2.7** and the Google-Cloud-SDK. This takes **hours** if I run it linearly. I was suggested **Apache Beam/DataFlow** to process in parallel.

**[+] What I've been able to do:**

I can read from one file, perform a PTransform and write to another file.

```
def loadMyFile(pipeline, path):
    return pipeline | "LOAD" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(path)

def myFilter(request):
    return request

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
    data = loadMyFile(pipeline,path)
    output = data | "FILTER" >> beam.Filter(myFilter)
    output | "WRITE" >> beam.io.WriteToText(google_cloud_options.staging_location)
```

**[+] What I want to do:**

How can I load many of those files simultaneously, perform the same transform to them in parallel, then in parallel write to big query?

[Diagram Of What I Wish to Perform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0ea7.png)

**[+] What I've Read:**

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/
http://enakai00.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/12/09/104913

Again, many thanks

Comment: I'll edit as the problem has now changed a little. Thanks for the response greenes

Answer (score 1):

`textio` accepts a [**file_pattern**](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html).

From Python sdk:

> > file_pattern (str) – The file path to read from as a local file path or a GCS gs:// path. The path can contain glob characters

For example, suppose you have a bunch of `*.txt` files in storage `gs://my-bucket/files/`, you can say:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
  (p 
  | "LOAD" >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(file_pattern="gs://my-bucket/files/*.txt")
  | "FILTER" >> beam.Filter(myFilter)
  | "WRITE" >> beam.io.textio.WriteToText(output_ocation)
```

If you somehow do have multiple `PCollections` of the same type, you can also [Flatten](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten) them into a single one

```
merged = (
  (pcoll1, pcoll2, pcoll3)
  # A list of tuples can be "piped" directly into a Flatten transform.
  | beam.Flatten())
```

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for but it was useful.

Comment: will it read/process those files in parallel, or will it start from the first byte of the first file, and continue sequentially to the last byte of last file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I resolved this by doing the following:

1) get the name of a bucket from somewhere | first PCollection

2) get a list of blobs from that bucket    | second PCollection

3) do a FlatMap to get blobs individually from the list | third PCollection

4) do a ParDo that gets the metadata

5) write to BigQuery

my pipeline looks like this:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipe:
        bucket      = pipe    | "GetBucketName"            >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://example_bucket_eraseme/bucketName.txt')
    listOfBlobs = bucket      | "GetListOfBlobs"           >> beam.ParDo(ExtractBlobs())
    blob        = listOfBlobs | "SplitBlobsIndividually"   >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: x)
    dic         = blob        | "GetMetaData"              >> beam.ParDo(ExtractMetadata())
    dic                       | "WriteToBigQuery"          >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
```